# Обновить страницу при повороте экрана

Tags: javascript

В проекте использую fullpage.js. Возникла следующая проблема: когда поворачиваешь экран на альбомную ориентацию сбивается верстка (захватывается 20px следующего блока). Эту проблему получилось решить с помощью автоматического обновления страницы. Но если обновляется страница на альбоме, то повернув смартфон в исходное состояние код снова обновляется и верстка ломается уже в обычном состоянии. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно исправить код, чтобы при повороте на альбомную ориентацию страница обновлялась, а при повороте на обычное положение смартфона не обновлялась.

```js
window.onorientationchange = function () {
    var orientation = window.orientation;
    switch (orientation) {
        case 0:
        case 90:
        case -90: window.location.reload();
            break;
    }
};
```

Comment: Какую версию `fullpage` используете?

Comment: На прошлой неделе начал использовать, версия 3.1.1

Comment: Хм, вроде нашёл [похожу проблему](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/248), там автор пофиксил это в `2.5.6`.. Но походу не оно.

Comment: Да, уже читал эту статью, но не нашел ответа

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте [window.matchMedia API](https://caniuse.com/?search=window.matchMedia):

```js
window.addEventListener('orientationchange', () => {
    const orientation = window.matchMedia('(orientation: landscape)')

    if (orientation.matches) {
        window.location.reload()
    }
})
```

Comment: не поддерживается для iOS Safari, а именно на нем я и тестирую

Comment: @VictorBej переделал с учетом поддержки iOS